# in ATK4, how do i use a template to create a filetype other than html?

Tags: php, css, templates, frameworks, atk4

The last remaining part of my original application that doesnt use atk4 is the dynamic css files created in php and outputing a css header. The width is determined based on the data in mysql and is needed to ensure the screen is not constantly resizing when notes are dragged around.

Where should i start if i want to create a .css file that has a template structure similar to the html templates so i can use a css definition like

```
.fullwidth {
   width:<?$width?>; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to re-write your CSS files through .htaccess. Create a page dedicated for creating the CSS on your system.

```
RewriteRule ^css/dynamic\.css$  index.php?page=css
```

Next create class inside page/css.php

```
class page_css extends Page {
    function init(){
        parent::init();
        echo ".fullwidth { ... } ";
        exit;
    }
}
```

In this case templates are not much of a help, but if you want to use one, remember to echo $template->render(); and exit.

Comment: If i add a defaultTemplate to that page, would it get populated ? And how do i refer to the css page, can i include it with         $this->api->template->append('css_include', '<link type="text/css" href="'.$this->api->locateURL('css','dynamic.css').'" rel="stylesheet" />'."\n");

Comment: defaultTemplate is rendered by recursive render which happens after init. If you exit early, it will never happen: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/api/exec

Regarding including CSS, I've already added the ["Static" JavaScript](http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/jsapi/import), but there are no static includes for stylesheets. Dedicated function will be added in 4.1.3 release, meanwhile use the code you posted. Except that locateURL wouldn't work, as such file wouldn't exist.

Comment: OK - i added a <?$css_include?> in my shared.html right above the existing js_include so i can add css but keep it separate from the javascript so i will give it a try. Thanks